# Read inconsistent file to arraylist java

Tags: java, arraylist, readfile

I have a file that has the following data:

```
19387,73616,11/10/2021,7268,8271
81716,16381,11/10/2021,2736,3715,7362,837
75464,27315,11/10/2021,,3545,7645,460
```

- The format is: id1, id2, yyyy/mm/dd, price, id3.
- There can be multiple id3s (some lines have more data).

The data types are: int, int, string, float, arraylist integer. So here, I only want to read id3 as an integer arraylist

My code so far:

```
Public static void main(String[] args){

  //variables
  int id1;
  int id2;
  String date;
  float price;
  ArrayList<Integer> id3List = new ArrayList<>();

  //check if file exists
  try {
      //get file
      File myFile = new File (“fileName.txt“);

      //pass file object to create scanner object
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner ("myFile").useDelimiter(",|\\r|\\n");
      
      //read lines from file and store into respective variables
      try {
        While (inputFile.hasNextInt){
          id1 = inputFile.nextInt();
          id2 = inputFile.nextInt();
          date = inputFile.next();
          price = inputFile.nextFloat();
          id3.add(inputFile.nextInt());

          inputFile.nextLine(); //consume a line 

      } catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("Bad data in file.");
      }
       System.out.println(id3);

       inputFile.close(); //close file

  } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
     System.out.println("The file was not found.");
    }
}
```

The result i get only displays the first id3 and ignores the rest:

```
[8271, 3715, 7645]
```

Note: I will only be using a scanner for this, not buffered reader.

Comment: Is there a reason why you only want to use a scanner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would do would be to separate the parsing of the file from the parsing of the text.

That is, read a line of text from the file, then, using a seperate `Scanner`, parse that line.

This allows you to seperate the logic and workflow without potentially messing it up (but, that's me).

You also need to take into account that if the `price` is empty, you will have a dangling element, which should be read (and discard).

Finally, make use of `hasNextInt` to loop through the remaining tokens

For example...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner("""
                                      19387,73616,11/10/2021,7268,8271
                                      81716,16381,11/10/2021,2736,3715,7362,837
                                      75464,27315,11/10/2021,,3545,7645,460
                                      """);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner line = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine()).useDelimiter(",");
            int id1 = line.nextInt();
            int id2 = line.nextInt();
            String date =  line.next();

            float price = 0;
            if (line.hasNextFloat()) {
                price = line.nextFloat(); 
            } else {
                line.next();
            }

            System.out.println(id1);
            System.out.println(id2);
            System.out.println(date);
            System.out.println(price);

            List<Integer> otherIds = new ArrayList<>(25);
            while (line.hasNextInt()) {
                otherIds.add(line.nextInt());
            }

            System.out.println(otherIds);

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This will print...

```
19387
73616
11/10/2021
7268.0
[8271]

81716
16381
11/10/2021
2736.0
[3715, 7362, 837]

75464
27315
11/10/2021
0.0
[3545, 7645, 460]
```

Answer (score -1):

You’re very close to the actual solution. In this case `inputFile.nextInt()` will return `NULL` when no more integers can be found. This is why we can use a while loop to append to the array.

```
while(inputFile.nextInt())
{
     id3.add(inputFile.nextInt());
}
```

Comment: *"inputFile.nextInt() will return NULL"* - I'm pretty sure it doesn't, have a read of the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()).  You are, however close to the idea

Comment: Sorry, you’re right. Didn't read the Docs. However, the idea of the while loop still holds.

Comment: Yes, the "idea" is correct, the implementation is not ;)

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking of using another while loop for the arraylist